# Почему в Хроме SetInterval работает быстрее, чем в IE или Edge?

Tags: javascript

Почему у меня в хроме `setInterval` работает быстрее, чем в IE или Edge ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var counter = 0;
            setInterval(function () {
                document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = counter;
                counter++;
            }, 1);
        }
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p id="res" style="position:absolute; top:200px; right:0; color:#000;"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

После 40 секунд counter = 10500 (Хром) и 3000 (Edge, IE). В чем причина?

Comment: одна миллисекунда? Не слишком ли часто?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[<strike>Согласно спецификации</strike> Часто](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval), при значении периода меньше 10 используется 10 (обратите внимание, [задержка может быть и выше](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified)), но, похоже, Chrome следует ей не очень-то аккуратно.

Comment: Вы ссылаетесь не на спеку а на популярное толкование, в спеке я пока чет такой строчки найти не могу. Ну то есть ответ в принципе верный (в том что у разных браузеров фактический минимальный таймаут разный). Но с конкретными цифрами я бы был поосторожнее)

Comment: Это не спецификация. Насколько я помню, в спецификации на месте 10 стоит 4.

Comment: По факту дальше на той же странице говорится про то что он 4ms в большинстве браузеров

Comment: @Qwertiy вот я тоже, но найти пока не могу =)

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка, нашёл, но что-то _nesting level_ настораживает...

Comment: @Qwertiy вот я тоже)

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, минимальный интервал таймера - это 4мс.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#timer-initialisation-steps

> If nesting level is greater than 5, and timeout is less than 4, then increase timeout to 4.

Во-вторых, js однопоточный и лишнее встаёт в очередь. Если успевает браузер за эти 4мс обновить dom (который меняется в обработчике), то он запускает следующий. А если не успевает - ну что ж, очередь подождёт.

Судя по всему, IE не успевает.

Comment: Эту строчку я тоже нашел, но я не уверен, что ее достаточно (считай не вкурил в алгоритм чтобы быть уверенным что любой таймер дойдет до nesting level greater than 5)